# Windows paging file size with 100GB RAM

Tags: windows, memory, virtual-memory, paging

My system has more than 100GB RAM. But when I have too many applications open or Tabs open, I feel the system is slowing down even though the RAM utilization is around 10-15 GB. My paging file size with automatic manage is 15360 MB. According to suggested size it should be 1.5 times the RAM, it doesn't make sense to keep a paging file that large with so much of RAM available.

My question is Why is it advisable to have such a big paging file size with so much of RAM available for system. Also, I feel the paging is making my system slow since it is utilizing the paging file instead of RAM. Since I keep my system running and tabs open for weeks.

Any suggestions to how much should I keep the size of my paging file?

Comment: IIRC paging shouldn't be used unless needed. And well with more than 100gb of ram, I don't think ram and paging is your bottleneck. You can't even put in that much on a modern mainstream system so you're probably running server grade hardware.

Comment: Yes, Its a server grade system with 2x processors on board and more than 100GB of ram. but since paging was automatically managed, when I checked it was more than 15GB. My understanding is since most of my tabs and application are open for weeks they will be stored in paging file even though there is plenty of memory available.
@JourneymanGeek so do you recommend I disable paging or keep it to very minimum to keep system performance high?

Comment: Best performance will nearly always be system managed. Performance of a browser I've longer term depends more on the browser code than the volume of memory installed. You're browser is guaranteed not to be written to make use of 100GB of ram. All you've done is made certain ram isn't the bottleneck.

Comment: Modern OSs will page out data when the system is idle, so that *in case* the system runs out of RAM, it doesn't need to swap out when the system is under high load. So, it's normal to have data in the page file, even if you have free RAM.

Comment: @JörgWMittag So if I disable paging file is there any risk of system malfunction?